# Inserting a string with time into a fixed-length sorted list of times

Tags: python, list

I have a piece of code, as below, where if a time is less than a value in a list of 5 times I want to insert the new value in the list and delete 5th value in the list, essentially updating the list with the new set of top five times.

```
hours=str(input('enter hours:'))
minutes=int(input('enter minutes:'))
seconds=int(input('enter seconds:'))

if minutes <10:
    minutes='0'+str(minutes)
if seconds <10:
    seconds='0'+str(seconds)
    
currentTime=hours+':'+str(minutes)+':'+str(seconds)
print(currentTime)
hours=int(currentTime[0])
minutes=int(currentTime[2]+currentTime[3])
seconds=int(currentTime[5]+currentTime[6])
print(hours, minutes, seconds)

for i in range(1,6):
    aTime=str(Times[0][i])
    print(Times[0][i])
    if hours==int(aTime[1]):
        if minutes==int(aTime[3]+aTime[4]):
            if seconds <=int(aTime[6]+aTime[7]):
                #equal values deemed quicker
                print('quicker time than time',str(i))
                #insert value in Times[0][i]
                break
        elif minutes<int(aTime[3]+aTime[4]):
            print('quicker time than time',str(i))
            #insert value in Times[0][i]
            break
    elif hours<int(aTime[1]):
        print('quicker time than time',str(i))
        #insert value in Times[0][i]
        break
```

Example of what I want this to achieve is if;

```
Times=['1:30:00','2:00:00','2:00:00','2:00:00','2:00:00']
```

and, for example, current `Time='1:45:00'`

That Times should become:

```
Times=['1:30:00','1:45:00','2:00:00','2:00:00','2:00:00']
```

Feel like this type of question has been asked before but couldn't find one.
Thanks In Advance.

Side note: I imagine that this is probably a very inefficient way of comparing the times but the method is correct just need to know how to insert a value into a list essentially.

Comment: hmmm, adding need elements to a list `mylist` is done with `mylist.append(item)` adding them into a specific position in that list is done with `mylist.insert(position,item)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range

Comment: and replacing a element in a given position is done by `mylist[position] = item`

Comment: Shouldn't it be easier to add at the end, and then just sort the list again ?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem that would be best solved by coming up with a data structure.

We'll call it a `MaxList` since:

- It only retains the minimum elements
- It has a maximum number of elements

```py
class MaxList:
    
    def __init__(self, size, remaining=None):
        self._size = size
        self._contents = []
        if remaining:
            self._contents = remaining

    def append(self, item):
        for i, entry in enumerate(self._contents):
            if item < entry:
                self._contents.insert(i, item)
                break
        self._contents = self._contents[:self._size]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._contents.__repr__()
```

This implementation assumes the list starts sorted, and works as follows:

```py
>>> ls = MaxList(5, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9])  # 5 is the total length, rest is the list
>>> ls
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> ls.append(8)
>>> ls
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8]    # `9` was pushed out
>>> ls.append(10)
>>> ls
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8]    # Notice `10` is not in the list
>>> ls.append(-1)
>>> ls
[-1, 1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> ls.append(-5)
>>> ls
[-5, -1, 1, 3, 5]
```

I'd recommend using a non-string representation for times: it will make it easier to compare and decide if one value is less than or greater than another. The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) objects in Python's standard library could be a good place to start.

For example:

```py
from datetime import time

times = MaxList(5, [
    time(1, 30, 0),
    time(2, 0, 0),
    time(2, 0, 0),
    time(2, 0, 0),
    time(2, 0, 0),
])

print(times)

times.append(time(1, 45, 0))

print(times)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.time(1, 30), datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(2, 0)]
[datetime.time(1, 30), datetime.time(1, 45), datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(2, 0)]
```

Comment: You could also make use of the `heapq` module here... If it's possible for the OP to refactor their input loop as a generator function and yield each value, then calling `heapq.nsmallest(5, input_function())` would work nicely

Answer (score 1):

```
timeint = int(newtime.replace(':', ''))
for n, i in enumerate(list):
    i = int(i.replace(':', ''))
    if i > timeint:
        list[n] = newtime
        break
print(list)
```

where newtime is the new time you are trying to compare and list is the list of previous times

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for this.

```
import bisect 

Times=['1:30:00','2:00:00','2:00:00','2:00:00','2:00:00']

Time='1:45:00'

Times[bisect.bisect(Times, Time)]=Time 

>>> Times
['1:30:00', '1:45:00', '2:00:00', '2:00:00', '2:00:00']
```

This only works, in general, for a list already sorted (yours is) with an element that that will compare to those elements in the desired way. String representations of times can be represented this way so that a lexical sorting can be maintained.

See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Time only strings are subset that can be treated the same way.

While strings will work, a *better* way to store and compare times and dates in Python is with the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. You can use the bisect module with datetime objects to insert into a sorted list the same way.